# WSO2 EI 6.6.0 Secure Vault Issue

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

We are trying to use secure vault to store our passwords. If we fetch the secret values from dblookup in sequence we are able to fetch the passwords. But we are not able to fetch the passwords from data source. Below are my code snippets.

DBLookup Code Snippet : From here we call our DB

```
    <insequence>
          <dblookup>
             <connection>
                                <pool>
                                <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
                                <url>myurl</url>
                                <user>username</user>
                                <password>{wso2:vault-lookup('username')}</password>
                                </pool>
                            </connection>
        </dblookup>
    </insequence>
            
<!--Datasource Code Snippet.From here we call our DB-->            
    

<datasource>
    <name>DataSource2</name>
    <description>DB to get data</description>
    <jndiConfig useDataSourceFactory="false">
        <name>DataSource2</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>
            <driverClassName>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driverClassName>
            <url>MyURL</url>
            <username>Username</username>
            <password>{wso2:vault-lookup('password')}</password>
        </configuration>
    </definition>
</datasource>

 

     <dblookup>
            <connection>
                <pool>
                    <dsName>DataSource2</dsName>
                </pool>
            </connection>          
         </dblookup>
```

How I can resolve this issue ?

Comment: is that `configuration` from mediaton or configuration file?

Comment: @usuario : Update code accordingly. Please help

Comment: How are you adding the Datasource?

Comment: We are adding this data source from integration studio not by console.

Comment: can you share the error that you are getting

Comment: Are you using vanilla pack or WUM updated. Seems registry based secure vault look up is added to EI.6.6 after the release https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/5335